# presentViewController causing crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios6

I'm working on an iPad app using cocos2d, and I'm trying to make it possible to either choose a picture from the library, or take a picture using the camera, to use within the app. I've been googling like mad all day yesterday and today to try and fudge together something to do the above, but I should probably begin by admitting that I don't really know what I'm doing.

The way I have it working right now, you tap the current user image, and it brings up a menu asking if you want to upload a different picture from the camera or the library. Choosing camera calls the following (and the library version is basically the same):

```
- (void) onGetCameraImage
{
    UIImagePickerController* imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;

    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [imagePicker presentViewController:[CCDirector sharedDirector] animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

When I try and test this (picking library, of course, since the simulator can't do camera, and yes I do intend to implement the check for no camera), I get the following crash:

```
2013-04-07 19:21:50.248 prototype1[20897:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller <UIImagePickerController: 0x9e87ac0>.'
```

I think it's crashing on the `presentViewController` call, but I'm having a terrible time trying to find out what I'm doing wrong because all of the tutorials and stackoverflow answers use the deprecated modal function call! I suspect I'm just doing all sorts of crazy BS in my previous code? Either way, I have no idea how to get my code to work.

A lot of this code has been gleaned from stack overflow, so I can't guarantee the sensibility of any of it - I'm very new to iOS coding, was basically thrown into this project and we're just trying to make it work. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes something seems wrong here. In order to achieve what you are after when you instantiate the `UIImagePickerController` you typically want the current view controller to present your image picker instance. The crash is happening becuase:

1. You are telling the imagepicker to present something from Cocos2D
2. The `UIImagePickerController` view is not even on screen yet

Do you have a access to a view controller?

If so, you can simply do something like the following:

```
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

where `self` is some subclass of `UIViewController`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That makes sense... I had thought that the sharedDirector was a subclass of UIViewController so I was trying to use it as the view controller, I think.

However, I know I can't just use self instead of imagePicker, since this is a subclass of CCLayerColor (and xcode yells at me if I try). I don't know what else I can try?

Comment: NO WAIT. I swapped [CCDirector sharedDirector] and imagePicker and it works... now I just get this error: `2013-04-07 20:05:31.678 prototype1[23030:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'On iPad, UIImagePickerController must be presented via UIPopoverController'` and I know what that means T.T

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sure let me know if you have any more trouble. With the combination of Cocos and UIKit things get overly complicated :-)

Comment: alright, now i'm trying to get it to use the UIPopoverController stuff... I'm getting a `reason: 'The content view controller argument must be the root of its associated view controller hierarchy.` error with this call: `[imagePicker presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(10, 10, size.width-20, size.height-20) inView:[CCDirector sharedDirector].view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];`

any clue how to fix? The answer might be really obvious, at this point I'm slightly tipsy as well as confused...

Comment: Just wanted to add an update, I think I've got everything (well, regarding this anyway, debugging a different crash now >.<) working :) thank you for your help - my biggest problem with this project right now is not knowing where to begin when things go wrong

Comment: Good glad to hear you got it working. If this advice helped please consider marking this as the correct answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

just change last line look like below

```
 [imagePicker presentViewController: imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score -1):

And one more thing, before setting

```
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera
```

you gotta check whether source type is available or not.

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

imagePicker.delegate = self;

imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;

[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];

[imagePicker release];

 }

 else
 {
 //.....
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew about that one, though, I had a comment in the code to put that in and I did finally get around to it <.<